# How to change status of an element

Tags: html

So i was checking the code of a page and i can see that scrolling down on the website an element div becomes from:

```
<div class="badge-entry-toolbar-sticky post-afterbar-a in-post-top" style=""></div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="badge-entry-toolbar-sticky post-afterbar-a in-post-top sticked" style="position: fixed; z-index: 3; top: 0px;"></div>
```

How this can be done?

Comment: This is essentially about styling an element and changing its class, with javascript. Please google it.

Comment: It's NOT the same div. Div 1 changes to Div 2 and receives style.

Comment: It is the same div. Using JS it adds class and inline-styles

Comment: Is there any way posible to do this without JS? Thank you for the reply. ALL of you

Answer (score 0):

It's called sticky header (element).

Here is an example on pure JS.

HTML:

```
<header class="header" role="banner">
    <!-- ... -->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$window = $(window);
$window.scroll(function() {
  $scroll_position = $window.scrollTop();
  if ($scroll_position > 300) { // if body is scrolled down by 300 pixels
    $('.header').addClass('sticky');
    header_height = $('.header').innerHeight();
    $('body').css('padding-top' , header_height);
  } else {
    $('body').css('padding-top' , '0');
    $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using JavaScript to change the state of the div.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.classList.add('sticky');
```

Answer (score -1):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L17sptbb/

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" class="oldclass">text</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').className = 'newclass';
```

CSS

```
.oldclass { color: blue }
.newclass { background-color: yellow }
```